# C: Printing out multiple threads' ID's before they execute anything?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, pthread-join

I am wanting to generate a number of threads based off of how many a user wishes to create, and each of these threads is to carry out one function "readFiles".  However, before the threads can each execute any of the meaningful code from readFiles, (represented by the "..." 's), I want ALL of the threads to each print out their thread ID's in a sort of introductory notification message, so something like...

```
"Thread ID _____ is processing!"
"Thread ID _____ is processing!"
"Thread ID _____ is processing!"
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

...but obviously with the code I have, each thread is only running one at a time so the thread ID's are only printing out when each new thread starts executing meaningful code, so this...

```
"Thread ID _____ is processing!"
    ...
"Thread ID _____ is processing!"
    ...
"Thread ID _____ is processing!"
    ...
```

Is there a way to get thread ID's before I call pthread_create() on each specific new thread?  Or is there a way in which I can make these threads (which are supposed to run concurrently), hold off or pause their execution of the meaningful code within readFiles (their "..." 's) until they have each printed out the thread ID messages first?  Thank you everybody so much!!!  This is my code to give you a better idea of what I have at the moment...

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

uint64_t gettid()
{
    pthread_t actual_tid = pthread_self();
    uint64_t threadId = 0;
    memcpy( &threadId, &actual_tid, sizeof( actual_tid ) );
    return threadId;
}


void *readFiles( void *args )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);


    uint64_t current_id = gettid();
    printf("Thread id = ");
    printf("%" PRIu64 , current_id );

    ...
    ...
    ...

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}


void alphabetcountmulthreads(int num_threads)
{

    pthread_t ids[num_threads];

    for ( int t = 0; t < num_threads; t++ )
    {
        
        if ( pthread_create( &ids[t], NULL, &readFiles, NULL ) != 0 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "error: Cannot create thread # %d\n", t );
            break;
        }
    }

    for ( int u = 0; u < num_threads; ++u )
    {
        if ( pthread_join( ids[u], NULL ) != 0 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "error: Cannot join thread # %d\N", u );
        }
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to implement a thread pool with each thread having an opportunity to do preparatory work, before all threads will start actual work, is to have an additional startup mutex, associated condition variable, and a counter for ready threads:

```
static pthread_mutex_t  prep_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t   prep_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static volatile size_t  prep_count = 0;

static pthread_mutex_t  thread_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static volatile size_t  thread_count = 0;

static inline pid_t gettid(void) { return syscall(SYS_gettid); }

static void *thread_function(void *idref)
{
    /* Get the number/index of this thread. */
    const size_t  num = *(pid_t *)idref;
    const pid_t   tid = gettid();

    /* Replace it with the Linux tid. */
    *(pid_t *)idref = tid;

    /* Block here until preparatory work can be done. */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&prep_mutex);

    printf("Thread %zu of %zu has started.\n", id + 1, thread_count);
    fflush(stdout);

    prep_count++;
    pthread_cond_signal(&prep_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&prep_mutex);

    /* Block until actual work can start. */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);
    ...
```

When creating the thread pool, the creator holds both mutexes. When it is ready to let the threads start the prep work, it releases the `prep_mutex`, waiting on the `prep_cond` until sufficient number of threads have completed preparatory work (`prep_count` is high enough).  Then, it releases the `thread_mutex`.

```
int start_threads(size_t max_count)
{
    pthread_t       thread_id[max_count];
    pid_t           linux_tid[max_count];
    pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    int             err = 0;

    /* Assume no threads currently running */
    prep_count = thread_count = 0;

    /* Shrink stack size; the default is too large. */
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 2*PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);

    /* Grab the mutexes, so the threads will block initially. */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&prep_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);

    while (thread_count < max_count) {
        linux_tid[thread_count] = thread_count;
        err = pthread_create(thread_id + thread_count, &attrs,
                             thread_function, linux_tid + thread_count);
        if (err)
            break;

        thread_count++;
    }

    /* Attributes are no longer needed. */
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    /* No threads created at all? */
    if (thread_count < 1) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prep_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);
        /* Return failure. */
        return err;
    }

    /* All threads have now been created; let them do prep work. */
    while (prep_count < thread_count) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&prep_cond, &prep_mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&prep_mutex);

    /* All threads have finished their prep work; start working. */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);

    ...
```

The above creates up to `max_num` threads, with their pthread IDs in `thread_id[]`, and their Linux tids in `linux_tid[]`.

When the thread starts, it gets a pointer to the location to store the Linux tid to.  Initially, that contains the index of the thread ("thread number", starting at 0), so `thread_function` grabs that as `num`, obtains the Linux tid as `tid`,  and stores it to the location given as a parameter.  This way, both the original thread and the created thread know the index (`num`), pthread ID (`thread_id[]`, `pthread_self()`), and Linux tid (`linux_tid[]` and `tid`).

Note how the arrays are dereferenced in the `pthread_create()` call.  If `array` is an array, and `index` is an index to it, then `&(array[index]) == array + index`.

Above, the `start_threads()` function does not assume it can start all `max_num` threads.  It does return with nonzero `errno` number if it cannot create any, but if it can create at least one thread, as soon as the threads can grab `prep_mutex`, the `thread_count` will reflect the correct number of threads in their gang.  (There is no reason to fail just because you were only able to create 53 worker threads instead of 54, say.)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways you could accomplish this. You could use signals - have each thread send a signal to a monitor thread of sorts and then wait to be told to run. Once the monitor thread has received all the signals, it signals the waiting threads to continue. You could also implement a similar solution with a condition variable or mutex to lock the threads until all threads have printed their IDs.

Comment: Why not just a simple condition variable? Or even have the thread hold a mutex while it creates the threads and not release it until it has printed out all the thread IDs? Each thread can then just momentarily acquire/release the mutex to ensure it can't make progress until the creating thread has printed its ID.